# Using template literals with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, templates, ecmascript-6, literals

I'm coding a Node.JS Discord bot and would like to have error messages stored in a separate JSON file. Though, in this JSON file there's template literals, like

```
{
    "error": "Oh snap! Better check this out: ${error}"
}
```

How would I go to use them?

Thanks,

Well I don't want to convert it, just a way to use it. Far from being a duplicate.

Comment: *"Well I don't want to convert it, just a way to use it."* Well, what you have is a string, not a template literal. The short answer would be: You cannot use it. So you either have to convert the string to a template literal (bad) or use a proper template library (good). All these things are explained in the duplicate.

Comment: I've found a way around. Thanks though.